# I'm looking for panel data on Merger and Acquisition

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, economics, time-series

I am looking for sources of available datasets on M&A. My preference would be for a clean panel dataset that might have previously been used for the purpose of studying the effect of M&A on either firms profits, or their R&D activity. I know that this is rather specific, but any broader suggestions on good sources for M&A data would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There is some data on UK M&A activity available here: https://data.gov.uk/dataset/mergers_and_acquisitions_involving_uk_companies
though you'll probably have to combine it with data from Google or Yahoo for post M&A effects.

Comment: Thanks John, the link you provided is a great resource for this purpose but would require a lot of work to put together. If I was looking to do new research on the effect of mergers that would be fine, but my objective is to try out some statistical methods and would prefer to play around with a complete and clean dataset (if one is out there). Thanks!

Comment: I stumbled on one someone who said he has worked on such data, @DeerHunter. However, I can't figure out how to contact him since no contact info is left